# Storing values to array and Counting total array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im storing age values inside an array using array push,

```
foreach($arrayagevalues as $value){


$arrayage21to30 = array();
$arrayage31to40 = array(); 
if($value['Age'] >= 21 && $value['Age'] <= 30)
{
array_push($arrayage21to30, $value['Age']);
}

if($value['Age'] >= 31 && $value['Age'] <= 40)
{
array_push($arrayage31to40, $value['Age']);
}

}
```

at the end I want to count the total values stored inside my array in $arrayage21to30 ans $arrayage31to40. I used count($arrayage21to30); but it doesnt return the total number of array values inside my array.

Is there any way on how I can count values of an array or the approach of storing values inside my array is wrong?

Comment: How about your issue, the 2 variables should be defined outside `foreach loop`.

Comment: What do you mean by `total values`, do you mean `sum`, if yes, see the last part of my answer, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$arrayage21to30` and `$arrayage31to40` should be out of `foreach`

just try this code:

```
 <?php
 $arrayage21to30 = array();
 $arrayage31to40 = array();
 foreach($arrayagevalues as $value)
 {

     if($value['Age'] >= 21 && $value['Age'] <= 30)
     {
         array_push($arrayage21to30, $value['Age']);
     }

     if($value['Age'] >= 31 && $value['Age'] <= 40)
     {
         array_push($arrayage31to40, $value['Age']);
     }
 }
 echo count($arrayage21to30), "\n";
 echo count($arrayage31to40), "\n";
```

if you want to calculate the sum, you can use `arrray_sum`:

```
 echo array_sum($arrayage21to30), "\n";
 echo array_sum($arrayage31to40), "\n";
```

Comment: I dont need the sum, I just need to count all the items inserted inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variables outside the foreach loop.

$arrayage21to30 = array();
$arrayage31to40 = array();

then continue foreach